# lookup for a signal (lookup of 2 consecutive points) in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have a data set. There is a signal triggered at one point: it change from 1 -> 0 ( I know the column number), the column looks like this

00000111111000022222233333 (transpose this line please)

I want to write a command that do this (not necessarily a macro)

if row(x) = = 1 && row (x+1) = = 0

return x

the problem is I don't know how to use IF(AND... without the row number...

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: What do you mean by your column looks like "00000111111000022222233333"?

Comment: Hi Jordan
Sorry I might simplified the problem, I mean, there are many "step-like" signals in this data set, and I am looking for a specific one, changing from a specific number to another specific number

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the column for the signal is B starting in row 1 then in another column (say C starting in C2 ) enter

```
=if(AND($B1=1,$B2=0),"Trigger","")
```

and copy down, then filter on Trigger

Comment: Hi Charles, thank you very much! This command works very well!

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will return the row number of the `1` that precedes the `0`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((myRng=1)*(OFFSET(myRng,1,0)=0)),ROW(myRng))
```

You did not write what you want to happen if there are multiple triggers.  The above will return the row number of the last trigger.

`myRng` cannot refer to the entire column, and could be replaced by, for example, `A1:A100`.  If you do that, you might as well replace the `OFFSET(myRng,1,0)` with `A2:A101` to make the formula non-volatile

Explanation:

```
(myRng=1)*(OFFSET(myRng,1,0)=0)
```

This multiplies each cell in `myRng` by the next cell.  If the first = 1, and the second = 0, then the factors resolve to `TRUE * TRUE` and returns a `1`.  So the above will return an array looking like:

```
{0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0}
```

Dividing that array into 1 returns an array of `DIV/0` errors or a `1`.

The LOOKUP formula will then return the position of the last `1` and, using an array of row numbers for `result_vector`, will match it appropriately.

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you very much for your answer. Sorry I think I oversimplified the problem. There are several triggers in this data set and I am looking for a specific one (might not be the first or the last). But I learnt from your answer so that to use the multiplication of 1 and 0 to locate the signal, that is very useful. I think I can use some AND condition. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: If you cannot figure it out, if you provide information as to what you really need, you'll get a better answer.  Mine can be adapted easily to many different types of problems, including even returning multiple triggers of the same type.